# Show 2 random entries based on checkbox in Super Table

Tags: craft3, plugin-supertable

I have a Super Table field (entryType) with a checkbox field "featuredIn" and some values.

[image]

This is how it looks when creating a entry:
[image]

I can't figure out how to mix "slice" and "orderBy RAND" with filtering by that field.

This does show me 2 random entries from all:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('blog').orderBy('RAND()').all() %}

{% for entry in entries|slice(0, 2) %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This shows me only the entries where "showInRandom" is checked (but not random and not only 2):

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog') if entry.entryType.featuredIn.contains('showInRandom') %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty confusing so this answer assumes the following:

You have a Super Table field named `entryType` with the following cells:

- `featuredIn` (checkbox)
- `showInRandom` (checkbox)

And that you are trying to:

1. Only show rows where `showInRandom` is checked
2. Randomize the order of the rows that are returned
3. Limit the returned results to 2

Unfortunately Super Table doesn't support searching based on a block's value, [which I see you already know](https://github.com/verbb/super-table/issues/290), so you'll have to do it in steps.

First, you need to pull in every Super Table row. Then you need to check if each row has `showInRandom` checked (side note: a lightswich field would be easier), and add its ID to an array if so. Then you randomize the array and run a Super Table query with those IDs and limit the results to 2.

```
{# create an array to store the returned IDs #}
{% set randomRows = [] %}

{# add only the rows with showInRandom selected to the array #}
{% for row in entry.entryType.all %}
    {% if row.showInRandom.options[0].selected %}
        {% set randomRows = randomRows|merge([row.id]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# randomize the array and run a super table query, limiting to 2 #}
{% for row in craft.superTable.blocks({
    owner: entry,
    fieldId: 123,
    id: shuffle(randomRows),
    fixedOrder: true,
    limit: 2
}).all %}
    {{ row.someField }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry that does not work. featuredIn is not a checkbox, it's a field. I did update the question with some screenshots. Seems like i don't get that checkbox thing. Because i also have a field "requiresLogin" and also can't figure out how to make that work.

Comment: @MrGlasspoole It would be easier if you updated your question specifically stating *exactly* what you are trying to do.